# Custom JSON response format in Phoenix

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix seems to have an unconventional way of serializing JSON (it's new to me anyway). For example, let's say I have a table with two columns - id, and name. In nearly every other web framework the response to the show endpoint would return JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo"
}
```

Using the Phoenix generators the response looks like this:

```
{
    "data": 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo"
    }
}
```

I'm seeing similar issues with POSTs, I need to post `{"company": { "name": "foo" } }` instead of `{ "name": "foo" }`.

I have two questions:

1. Is there an advantage to serializing JSON this way that I'm unaware of?
2. Is there a way to handle JSON serialization in the "normal" way as described above?

Comment: With your way, how do you represent errors in the responses?

Comment: Clients primarily use HTTP status codes. For further detail they can look at the response body, typically this is JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think that comes down to personal preference.
2. You can change it of course.

In the generated view, change it from

```
def render("show.json", %{id: id, name: name}) do
  %{
    data: %{
      id: id,
      name: name
    }
  }
end
```

to

```
def render("show.json", %{id: id, name: name}) do
  %{
    id: id,
    name: name
  }
end
```

And in your controller function which accepts JSON from:

```
def create(conn, %{"company" => %{"name" => name}}) do
  ...
end
```

to

```
def create(conn, %{"name" => name}) do
  ...
end
```

Your generated functions might look different but I think you get the point.

Comment: 1. is not entirely true: With this approach, you will additionally have to define every column in your controller (`create` function), so it will be harder to maintain.

Comment: You don't have to pattern match. You can also pass the whole params map into your changeset and let it pick the keys it needs.

Comment: @Phillipp this got me very close. How do I handle the signature of the `update` controller method since `id` comes from the path and `company_params` is from the request body? It's currently `def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "company" => company_params})`.

Comment: @user140550 They should be mixed together, so you can pattern match on `%{"id" => id, "name" => name}` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Posting diffs of Phoenix 1.3.0 generated code so that it might help others:

Controller changes

```
-  def create(conn, %{"company" => company_params}) do
+  def create(conn, company_params) do

-  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "company" => company_params}) do
-    company = Repo.get!(Company, id)
+  def update(conn, company_params) do
+    company = Repo.get!(Company, conn.path_params["id"])
```

View changes

```
   def render("index.json", %{companies: companies}) do
-    %{data: render_many(companies, ConstructApi.CompanyView, "company.json")}
+    render_many(companies, ConstructApi.CompanyView, "company.json")
   end

   def render("show.json", %{company: company}) do
-    %{data: render_one(company, ConstructApi.CompanyView, "company.json")}
+    render_one(company, ConstructApi.CompanyView, "company.json")
   end
```